# Multiple jquery effects doesn't work in my html script

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my html design, I have a jquery menubar and a slider....I need to use an image gallery and a jquery calender in my page...But when I use gallery and calender,it doesn't work...What's the reason???

Comment: it may be because of jquery conflit

Comment: Hey my car doen't work any more. What's the reason???

Comment: We need way more information than this, can you provide your code? Make sure you post it here, SO is for helping other people too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are loading the jQuery library twice. 
And maybe you are having a jquery conflict.

Maybe you can give us a link so we can see whats wrong?

Comment: Code would be better, links can become invalid over time.

Comment: Yea, that's a better idea :)

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>scanatenant.com</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: There is your answer. If you take a closer look, you will see this twice: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
You are loading the jquery libary twice. Delete one.

Comment: Just for future reference @vyshakh, you can edit your question and add the HTML to your question instead. Comments are pretty hard to read, and aren't immediately easy to find...